# Excel formula to find a conditional minimum of visible cells only

Tags: excel, excel-formula, aggregate, array-formulas, subtotal

At first I must to apologize if I did some translation mistakes of formula names. It will be hard to describe what I need because Polish Excel formula names are totally different than English ones and it is not possible to switch between languages and the names in Excel. But let's try...

I know solutions to find a conditional minimum using e.g. `{=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$10=$A11;$B$2:$B$10;""))}` array formula and to find a minimum of a filtered group of cells (minimum of visible cells only) using e.g. `SUBTOTAL(105;$B$2:$B$10)` or `AGGREGATE(5;3;$B$2:$B$10)` formulas but I can't find a way to merge both these solutions together to get the minimum of all visible cells meeting the condition.

In other words I need to get the minimum value of visible cells only in the range `B2:B10`, but only from rows where the value in the range `A2:A10` is equal to a particular value in the cell `A11` and the value in `B2:B10` is greater then zero.

```
+---+-----+
| A |  B  |
+---+-----+
| 1 | 170 |
........... <== here some hidden (filtered or grouped) rows with other values
| 1 | 120 |
| 1 | 100 | <== minimum for "1"
| 1 |   0 | <== not included for "1" - only > 0
| 2 | 110 |
........... <== here some hidden (filtered or grouped) rows with other values
| 2 | 109 |
| 2 | 105 | <== minimum for "2"
| 3 |  50 | <== minimum for "3"
| 3 |   0 | <== not included for "3" - only > 0
+===+=====+
| 1 | 100 |  <= expected results of formula - minimum values, greater then zero, for groups "1", "2" and "3"
| 2 | 105 |
| 3 |  50 |
+---+-----+
```

Kind regards - McVik

Answer (score 2):

Use AGGREGATE(15,7,...), which allows array processing:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,$B$2:$B$10/(($A$2:$A$10=$F12)*($B$2:$B$10>0)*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($B$2,ROW($B$2:$B$10)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$10)),,1)))),1)
```

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner, but it doesn't work for me as expected on grouped / filtered rows. The minimum value I'm getting is the minimum from the whole range, not only from visible cells.

Comment: it works same as `{=MIN.K(IF($A$2:$A$10=$A11;IF($B$2:$B$10>0;$B$2:$B$10;"");"");1)}` and easier `{=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$10=$A11;IF($B$2:$B$10>0;$B$2:$B$10;"");""))}`.

Comment: Almost perfect. ;-) Ignoring the fact that I was already confused somewhere near the "OFFSET" ;-) I translated it to my local Excel and it still didn't work for me. After few attempts I found that it works only with filtered rows, but unfortunately doesn't work with grouped rows. 
In my first post I probably wasn't clear enough writing about "filtered group of cells". I have grouped cells and my examples with "SUBTOTAL" or "AGGREGATE" formulas worked on filtered and grouped cells so I didn't know that it sometimes makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I helped myself temporary by adding a "technical" column (e.g. "C") with a simple formula in each cell

```
=SUBTOTAL(103,$B2)
=SUBTOTAL(103,$B3)
=SUBTOTAL(103,$B4)
... etc.
```

and the final **array formulas** check if the value in this column equals 1.

```
{=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$10=$A11,IF($B$2:$B$10>0,IF($C$2:$C$10=1,$B$2:$B$10,""),""),""))}
{=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$10=$A12,IF($B$2:$B$10>0,IF($C$2:$C$10=1,$B$2:$B$10,""),""),""))}
{=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$10=$A13,IF($B$2:$B$10>0,IF($C$2:$C$10=1,$B$2:$B$10,""),""),""))}
```

And now it works exactly as I expected.

PS. Excuse me for using semicolons in my examples. My Excel localisation requires semicolons instead of commas (as I see you use in English version).

Regards - McVik